# Passing extras between activities and forwarding them to a single activity

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult, subactivity

My app is a basic login app that at the end will present all values user input for the fields in other activities. I am working with intent objects and flags. The activities use:

- intent extras to store the key-values,
- FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT
- startActivityForResult() and onActivityForResult() methods

So, activities named as AActivity, BActivity, Caactivity and the navigation flow must be: A → B → C → A with results from B and C.

My understanding with the logic of the code is that this tells Android that activity 3 should forward its result back to the activity that called activity 2, which is activity 1 in this case. And also when activity 3 sets its result and finishes, onActivityResult()in activity 1 will be called with the result data sent from activity 3.

However, when I run the app, I get the results from only activity 3, but receive null from activity 2, which is displayed in TextView in activity 1 as null,null,valueC,valueC, as shown in the picture.
[click for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvVux.png)

I googled and searched for the similar issues arised, yet couldn't solve the problem.

Thank you in advance for your help

Here are my codes:

AActivity:

```
public class AActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

Button btnStart;
TextView userDetails;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

    userDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userdetails);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activityAIntent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(activityAIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

        String return_userName = data.getExtras().getString("username");
        String return_userPassword = data.getExtras().getString("password");
        String return_secretQuestion = data.getExtras().getString("secretquestion");
        String return_secretAnswer = data.getExtras().getString("secretanswer");
        userDetails.setText("Your details: " + return_userName + "," + return_userPassword +
                "," + return_secretQuestion + "," + return_secretAnswer);
    }
}
```

}

BActivity:

```
public class BActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText userName,userPassword;
Button btnCancel,btnNext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    userName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    userPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userpassword);
    btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
    btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnnext);

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_back_to_a = new Intent(BActivity.this,AActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_back_to_a);
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activityCIntent = new Intent(BActivity.this,CActivity.class);
            activityBIntent.putExtra("username",userName.getText().toString());
            activityBIntent.putExtra("password",userPassword.getText().toString());
            intent_to_c.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
            startActivity(activityBIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

CActivity:

```
public class CActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText secretQuestion, secretAnswer;
Button btnCancel,btnNext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);

    secretQuestion =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.secretquestion);
    secretAnswer =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.secretanswer);
    btnCancel =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
    btnNext =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnnext);

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_back_to_a = new Intent(CActivity.this,AActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_back_to_a);
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent data = new Intent(CActivity.this,AActivity.class);
            data.putExtra("secretquestion",secretQuestion.getText().toString());
            data.putExtra("secretanswer",secretAnswer.getText().toString());

            setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**FOUND SOLUTION**

Hi. Finally I have figured out what I was doing wrong. So, the mistake was basically at Activity C, where I was creating a new intent and adding extras to it to be passed to Activity A, instead of catching the forwarded intent from 2 and add extras to merge with the already existing intent.

Having modified it and making a small change in onActivirtForResult() method of Activity A, now I perfectly get all of the values in Activity A entered from other Activities.

Hope my solution will be helpful others as well. So the changes are as follow:

in CActivity:

```
 btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activityBIntent = getIntent();
            activityBIntent.putExtra("secretquestion",secretQuestion.getText().toString());
            activityBIntent.putExtra("secretanswer",secretAnswer.getText().toString());

            setResult(RESULT_OK,activityBIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

and in AActivity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String value_username = data.getExtras().getString("username");
                String value_password = data.getExtras().getString("password");
                String value_secretquestion = data.getExtras().getString("secretquestion");
                String value_secretanswer = data.getExtras().getString("secretanswer");
                userDetails.setText(value_username + value_password + value_secretquestion + value_secretanswer);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```